# Exception com.facebook.react.common.c: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

Got issue from crash report play console.

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.68.6",

[image]